# Jquery: Replace values from one array to another

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, foreach

I have 2 arrays that have the exact same number of keys. I would like to loop through the first array, then search `<p>` tags for any matching values. Then if a match is found, I would like to replace that matching value with the corresponding value from the 2nd array.

I have this for now:

```
var text_original = ["original_word1", "original_word2", "original_word3"];
var text_replaced = ["replaced_word1","replaced_word2","replaced_word3"];
var z;

for (z = 0; z <= text_original.length; ++z) {
  $("p").each(function(){
    var text=jQuery(this).html();
    $(this).html(text.replace(text_original,text_replaced));
  });
}
```

This is the general idea, I'm getting confused how to isolate the single values from the multiple array values.  Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, this is minimal, and I can't produce the code that I don't know how to write in the first place.  If I gave everything, it would complicate worse.

Comment: Please, post the content of the two arrays.

Comment: Oh ok.  Coming right up - thanks!

Comment: Doing this `$("p")` for ech iteration is a bad practice.

Comment: Ok I provided a few example arrays, just to make cleaner.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: Did you check my answer?  It's a good approach to avoid unnecesary iterations, avoid repeated look up using `$('p')` for each iteration and it's DRY.  Further, you're using the function `html` which in this case is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You missing `echo` before `json_encode()`.
- Your `json_encode()` should not be wrapped into quotes.
- You have to use `[z]` to access to an element of an array.

Code :

```
var text_original = <?php echo json_encode($text_original); ?>;
var text_replaced = <?php echo json_encode($text_replaced); ?>;
var z;
for (z = 0; z <= text_original.length; ++z) {
    $("p").each(function(){
        var text=jQuery(this).html();
        $(this).html(text.replace(text_original[z],text_replaced[z]));
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Syscall, I edited the original question to be slightly different.  Nevermind the PHP code I originally placed.  Sorry for that.  Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant, and simple.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

- Use the function `indexOf` and check for the found text.
- Use the function `text` rather than the function `html`.

```js
var text_original = ["original_word1", "original_word2", "original_word3"];
var text_replaced = ["replaced_word1", "replaced_word2", "replaced_word3"];

$('p').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  
  var index = text_original.indexOf(text);
  if (index > -1) $(this).text(text.replace(text_original[index], text_replaced[index]));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>original_word1</p>
<p>original_word2</p>
<p>Ele from SO</p>
```

#### Why `$.text()`?

> The HTML [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) element represents a paragraph of text. Paragraphs are usually represented in visual media as blocks of text that are separated from adjacent blocks by vertical blank space and/or first-line indentation. Paragraphs are block-level elements.

The function `$.text()` will return the text without HTML tags.